# Shared Preference in CustomlistAdapter

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i need to store values in sharedpreference from customlistadapter.when i click the listview,Edittext alert box will open .in that alert box we can give quantity value.if i click the "OK"button in alert box that quantity value should save in shared preference.In my case app is crashing when i click listview.help me to find solution.Thanks in Advance.

```
public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Movie> movieItems1,int Groupid,Context context) 
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems1;
        this.Groupid=Groupid;
        this.c=context;
        //this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        this.arraylist=movieItems1;

    }




    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        // TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        // TextView year = (TextView)
        // convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);

        /*quantityTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                handleQuntityClickEvent(position);

            }
        });*/




       MainActivity.listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
            {



                handleQuntityClickEvent(position,Groupid);




            }
        });


        // getting movie data for the row
        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);


        title.setText(m.getTitle());

        quantityTextView.setText("" + m.getQuantity());



        rating.setText(m.getGenre().get(0) + " "+ m.getProductscale() + " " +"Rs."+ String.valueOf(m.getGenre().get(1)));


        String genreStr = "";
        for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
            genreStr += str + ", ";
        }
        genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
                genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
        // genre.setText(genreStr);

        // release year
        // year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));




        return convertView;
    }

    /** 
     * launch a edi
     * 
     * @param position
     */
    protected void handleQuntityClickEvent(int position, final int Groupid) {
        // TODO launch a dialog with edittext. The view has OK and Cancel
        // button. if the OK button pressed then
        this.mPosition = position;

        Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        final EditText editText = new EditText(activity);

        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
        editText.setHint("Quantity");
        editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        alertDialog.setView(editText);// set a editext view here
        alertDialog.setTitle("Add Quantity");


      sharedpreferences = c.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         final Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();



        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {



                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                    {


                        //SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 


                          editor.putInt("Userid", Groupid);
                         editor.commit(); 

                        handleOkButtonPressed(editText);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

logcat

```
 01-06 16:58:31.281: E/AndroidRuntime(16893): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-06 16:58:31.281: E/AndroidRuntime(16893): java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-06 16:58:31.281: E/AndroidRuntime(16893):    at com.telveg.adater.CustomListAdapter.handleQuntityClickEvent(CustomListAdapter.java:196)
    01-06 16:58:31.281: E/AndroidRuntime(16893):    at com.telveg.adater.CustomListAdapter$1.onItemClick(CustomListAdapter.java:127)
    01-06 16:58:31.281: E/AndroidRuntime(16893):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
    01-06 16:58:31.281: E/AndroidRuntime(16893):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1508)
    01-06 16:58:31.281: E/AndroidRuntime(16893):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3293)
    01-06 16:58:31.281: E/AndroidRuntime(16893):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4554)
    01-06 16:58:31.281: E/AndroidRuntime(16893):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    01-06 16:58:31.281: E/AndroidRuntime(16893):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    01-06 16:58:31.281: E/AndroidRuntime(16893):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    01-06 16:58:31.281: E/AndroidRuntime(16893):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
    01-06 16:58:31.281: E/AndroidRuntime(16893):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-06 16:58:31.281: E/AndroidRuntime(16893):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    01-06 16:58:31.281: E/AndroidRuntime(16893):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
    01-06 16:58:31.281: E/AndroidRuntime(16893):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    01-06 16:58:31.281: E/AndroidRuntime(16893):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Also add Logcat detail

Comment: why you are adding `setOnItemClickListener` to listview inside `getView` method ?

Comment: Logcat added @Kat-hat

Comment: This error is due to some null value..Call the setOnItemClickListener in  main activity instead of inside getview() and also you can save position,Groupid in sharedPreferences to get value in main activity

Comment: @VibinRejiY: probably `alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);` line causing issue

Comment: check inside setOnItemClickListener check Groupid value in logcat.May be you are not getting Groupid value

Comment: printed the value of Groupid. It is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line

```
MainActivity.listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
```

use

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(){
handleQuntityClickEvent(position,Groupid);
}
```

and move this code block inside **getView()**